# Provide Students with TeX Question Template

Tags: compiling, exam, sourcecode

I am an instructor, and I prepare homework assignments using the `\documentclass{exam}`.  I know that when I compile to PDF I can use `\documentclass[answers]{exam}` to generate a compiled PDF that contains solutions.

A student recently asked me for a TeX template that they can use to write their solutions into.

Of course, I don't want to provide ALL the TeX required---because it already has MY solutions in it, and it wouldn't be much of an assignment if they already had the answers!

Instead, I'd like to "compile" my TeX into a student template TeX file that they can edit, compile to their own PDF, and turn in.

**Is there a simple tool which can take a TeX document prepared with the exam documentclass and produce another TeX file (that is, source code) that is just the questions?**

Comment: You should also look at the eforms package.  It can only handle multiple choice or text answers, not latex source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the route I settled on.  It uses the multi-line regex matching of vim to chop out everything I wrote between each `\begin{solution}` and `\end{solution}`.

Makefile:

```
TEX=pdflatex -halt-on-error -interaction=nonstopmode

example-%.pdf: example-%.tex
    $(TEX) example-$*
    $(TEX) example-$*
    $(TEX) example-$*

template-%.pdf: template-%.tex
    $(TEX) example-$*
    $(TEX) example-$*
    $(TEX) example-$*

template-%.tex: example-%.tex
    cat example-$*.tex | vim -c ":%s/\\\\begin{solution}\_.\{-}\\\\end{solution}/\\\\begin{solution}\\\\end{solution}/g" -c "w! template-$*.tex" -c ":q!" -
```

Then, for example-01.tex I can put

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Homework 01 Example for Template}
\author{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27873/evanb}{evanb}}
\date{Due Date Goes Here}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}
    \question Recall Euler's identity, $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin \theta$.
        \begin{parts}
            \part Express $\cos\theta$ in terms of $e^{+i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.
                \begin{solution}
                    Cosine is even and sine is odd. 
                    Add the two exponentials together to get
                    \begin{align*}
                        e^{+i\theta} + e^{-i\theta} 
                            &= (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) + (\cos (-\theta) + i\sin(-\theta)) \\
                            &= (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) + (+\cos \theta - i\sin\theta) \\
                            &= 2 \cos\theta + 0 i \sin \theta
                    \end{align*}
                    Divide both sides to find
                    \begin{equation*}
                        \cos\theta = \frac{e^{+i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2}
                    \end{equation*}
                \end{solution}
            \part Express $\sin\theta$ in terms of $e^{+i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.
                \begin{solution}Just as in the previous part, but subtract.
                    \begin{equation*}
                        \sin\theta = \frac{e^{+i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2i}
                    \end{equation*}
                    One of the most common careless mistakes is to forget the $i$ downstairs!
                \end{solution}
            \part Using the expressions you found above, show $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$.
                \begin{solution}
                    Just expand!  The left hand side is
                    \begin{equation*}\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{e^{+i(\alpha+\beta)} + e^{-i(\alpha+\beta)}}{2}\end{equation*}
                    The right-hand side is
                    \begin{align*}
                        \cos\alpha \cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta
                        &=  \left(\frac{e^{+i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}\right)
                            \left(\frac{e^{+i\beta}+e^{-i\beta}}{2}\right)
                            - \left(\frac{e^{+i\alpha}-e^{-i\alpha}}{2i}\right)
                            \left(\frac{e^{+i\beta}-e^{-i\beta}}{2i} \right)\\
                        &=  \frac{e^{+i(\alpha+\beta)} + e^{+i(\alpha-\beta)} + e^{-i(\alpha-\beta)} + e^{-i(\alpha+\beta)}}{4} \\
                        &\phantom{=} -\frac{e^{+i(\alpha+\beta)} - e^{+i(\alpha-\beta)} - e^{-i(\alpha-\beta)} + e^{-i(\alpha+\beta)}}{4i^2}  \\
                        &=  \frac{e^{+i(\alpha+\beta)} + e^{-i(\alpha+\beta)}}{2}
                    \end{align*}
                    after a lot of cancellation and simplification (don't forget the $i^2$ in the basement of the sine term!).  I know personally I can never remember the angle-addition formulas.  So here is a way to derive them!
                \end{solution}
        \end{parts}


    \question Solve these simple differential equations.  Specify what parts of your solutions are arbitrary constants.  Explain where this differential equation might be useful and give the constants a meaning if you can.

\begin{parts}
    \part $y' = m$ with $m$ constant and $x$ the independent variable.
        \begin{solution}
            It's a line.
            $y(x) = mx+b$ with $b$ that can be set by the $y$ intercept of the line (for example).
        \end{solution}
    \part $\ddot{y} = -g$ with $g$ constant and $t$ the independent variable.
        \begin{solution}
            $y(t) = y_0 + v_0 t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$ where $v_0$ and $y_0$ are arbitrary constants.  They are fixed by the initial conditions.  This equation arises when something falls under the influence of constant gravity.  Then, $y_0$ could be the initial height and $v_0$ the initial velocity.

            To show that this is the solution, you can integrate it.  Or, you can `guess' it and just plug it in!
        \end{solution}
    
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

which can be compiled to PDF with `make example-01.pdf` either as an assignment or as a key (with or without `[answers]` in the `documentclass`).  But also with `make template-01.tex` to get a new file (`template-01.tex`),

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Homework 01 Example for Template}
\author{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27873/evanb}{evanb}}
\date{Due Date Goes Here}

\maketitle

\begin{questions}
    \question Recall Euler's identity, $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin \theta$.
        \begin{parts}
            \part Express $\cos\theta$ in terms of $e^{+i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.
                \begin{solution}\end{solution}
            \part Express $\sin\theta$ in terms of $e^{+i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$.
                \begin{solution}\end{solution}
            \part Using the expressions you found above, show $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$.
                \begin{solution}\end{solution}
        \end{parts}


    \question Solve these simple differential equations.  Specify what parts of your solutions are arbitrary constants.  Explain where this differential equation might be useful and give the constants a meaning if you can.

\begin{parts}
    \part $y' = m$ with $m$ constant and $x$ the independent variable.
        \begin{solution}\end{solution}
    \part $\ddot{y} = -g$ with $g$ constant and $t$ the independent variable.
        \begin{solution}\end{solution}
    
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

that has all the spaces for solutions (with `\begin{solution}\end{solution}`) but without any of the solutions I prepared.  That document can be equally well compiled via `make template-01.pdf`

So, I can distribute `template-01.tex` to the students so that they may compile a PDF of their own answers.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a LaTeX file to add answers to the questions, using the same filename with Answer appended (e.g. test.tex and testAnswer.tex).

You will need to add `\AnswerSpace` after each question, and reserve space for the answers.  Alas, you can't use `\vfill` as the distance isn't available until the page is completed.

```
\documentclass{exam}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\AtBeginDocument{\newwrite\ExamAnswer
  \immediate\openout\ExamAnswer{\jobname Answer.tex}%
  \immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\documentclass{exam}}%
  \immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\usepackage{graphicx}}%
  \immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\AddToHook{shipout/background}%
    {\string\put(0pt,-\the\paperheight){\string\includegraphics[page=\string\thepage]{\jobname.pdf}}}}%
  \immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\begin{document}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\end{document}}%
  \closeout\ExamAnswer
}
\newcommand\AnswerSpace{\par\immediate\write\ExamAnswer{\string\par
  \string\ifnum\string\value{page}<\thepage\string\relax \string\newpage\string\fi
  \string\vspace*{\string\dimexpr\the\pagetotal-\string\pagetotal}Answer \thequestion\string\par}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
How high is up?
\AnswerSpace
\vspace{1in}
\question
Where have all the flowers gone?
\AnswerSpace
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```